# rake default task how find source files?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rake

How can I find which tasks related to **default** rake task.

when I rub **rake**
rspec and cucumber tasks executed simultaneously but there is no any code in Rakefile 
and also **rake -T** don't show any details.

How can find source files for rake default task?
or find all files with task definitions

Comment: seems like **rake -W | grep 'default' ** do the trick. rake -P also can show you info

Comment: **rake -W** really do the tricks. I was very puzzled unable to find where is the rake file for **rake test** and **rake db**. Thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[Rails default rake tasks](https://github.com/rails/rails/tree/master/railties/lib/rails/tasks) has all the rails default rake files

`rake -P` lists all the rake tasks

Comment: I think https://github.com/rspec/rspec-rails/blob/master/lib/rspec/rails/tasks/rspec.rake also included but how can I get files list. is it possible ?